# Pandas bar plot to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to convert a bar chart figure into a numpy array.
I am doing so using the code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)    

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

df.plot.bar()

plt.savefig('curr_bar_chart.png')

numpy_array = fig2data(fig)
plt.close()
im = data2img(numpy_array)
```

At the end of the question I also attach the code for `fig2data` and `data2img`.

My problem:
The image that is saved (`curr_bar_chart.png`) shows up fine, but when viewing the final image using `im.show()` I get a plot without any data (i.e. empty plot with axes).

This is very puzzling since this setup works for me for other matplotlib plots that I am using elsewhere.

As promised, the rest of the code:

```
 def fig2data(fig):
    """
    @brief Convert a Matplotlib figure to a 4D numpy array with RGBA channels and return it
    @param fig a matplotlib figure
    @return a numpy 3D array of RGBA values
    """
    # draw the renderer
    fig.canvas.draw()

    # Get the RGBA buffer from the figure
    w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
    buf = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=np.uint8)
    buf.shape = (w, h, 4)

    # canvas.tostring_argb give pixmap in ARGB mode. Roll the ALPHA channel to have it in RGBA mode
    buf = np.roll(buf, 3, axis=2)
    return buf

def data2img ( data ):
    """
    @brief Convert a Matplotlib figure to a PIL Image in RGBA format and return it
    @param fig a matplotlib figure
    @return a Python Imaging Library ( PIL ) image
    """
    # put the figure pixmap into a numpy array
    w, h, d = data.shape
    return Image.frombytes( "RGBA", ( w ,h ), data.tostring( ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `fig` is indeed empty. You can see this by `plt.show()` in place of `plt.savefig('curr_bar_chart.png')`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)    

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

df.plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

You would end up seeing two figures and this first one (empty) is your `fig`. To fix this, you can pass the axes of `fig` to pandas bar plot. You would then get one single plot, which is your `fig`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)    

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

df.plot.bar(ax = ax)

plt.savefig('curr_bar_chart.png')

numpy_array = fig2data(fig)
plt.close()
im = data2img(numpy_array)
im.show()
```